# Why can't I use gcc-9.3.0 on Linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, installation

I installed gcc-9.3.0 by apt, but I can only use it with sudo like

```
sudo gcc --version
```

```
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO 
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

and

```
gcc --version
```

```
gcc (OpenFOAM) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I want to use it without sudo.
What is the difference?
How can I use gcc-9.3.0 from my normal user account?

Comment: What are your `PATH` with both user? Did you try to find gcc with find?: `find / -name gcc 2> /dev/null`

Comment: Actually, I suspect the user account has a custom version of gcc installed. Try `which gcc` and then `sudo which gcc` and see what the difference is. If there's a weird directory for the first one, check your $PATH to see if it's been added.

Comment: As you said, I tried to check the $PATH and added the installed directory to it, then it worked. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC doesn't need special `sudo` rights - the difference you see is because you have 2 versions installed, but version 6 appears in your regular `PATH` before version 9.

To fix it, add the install directory of GCC 9 to the front of your `PATH`.